# Create a menu and a submenu

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

I'm trying to create a menu and a submenu in wordpress, here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-config.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php ');

require_once ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/acesso-rapido/layouts/admin-layout.php';
    class Menu{
        
        // Propriedades (variáveis de classe)
        private $PageTitle;
        private $MenuTitle;
        private $Capability;
        private $MenuSlug;
        private $Function;
        private $IconUrl;
        private $Position;

        // Método construtor
        public function __construct($Capability, $MenuSlug) {
            $this->Capability = $Capability;
            $this->MenuSlug = $MenuSlug;

            $this->PageTitle = "Acesso Rapido";
            $this->MenuTitle = "Acesso Rapido";
            $this->Function = 'LayoutPageAdmin';
            $this->IconUrl = 'dashicons-store';
            $this->Position = 7;
            
            
            wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.5.2', true);

            do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carregar_bootstrap');
        }

        public function CallAdminMenu(){
            add_action('admin_menu',
            add_menu_page(
                $this->PageTitle,
                $this->MenuTitle,
                $this->Capability,
                $this->MenuSlug,
                $this->Function,
                $this->IconUrl,
                $this->Position,
            ));
        }

        public function CallAdminSubMenu($page_title, $menu_title, $parent_slug, $menu_slug, $callback, $position){
            add_action('admin_menu', add_submenu_page(
                
                $this->MenuSlug,
                $page_title,
                $menu_title,
                'manage_options',
                $menu_slug,
                $callback,
                $position,
            ), 99);
        }
        
        public function RenderAdminPage(){
            // include_once '../layouts/admin-layout.php';          
        }   
    }

?>
```

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Acesso Rápido
 * Author: Bruno Lima
 **/
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-config.php');

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( is_admin() ) {
    // we are in admin mode
    
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/acesso-rapido/componentes/menu-admin.php');
    
    $MenuAdmin = new Menu('manage_options', 'layouts/admin-layout.php');

    add_action('admin-menu',$MenuAdmin->CallAdminMenu());

    $MenuAdmin->CallAdminSubMenu('Adicionar Link Acesso Rápido',
                                    'Adicionar Link',
                                    'layouts/admin-layout.php',
                                    'layouts/admin-edit-acesso-rapido.php',
                                    'EditAcessoRapidoPage',
                                    1);
}

?>
```

But somehow, the submenu is redirecting to http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/layouts/admin-edit-acesso-rapido.php and not to a page into the administrative panel. I noticed that the url in the ul list is:

```
<a href="layouts/admin-edit-acesso-rapido.php">Adicionar Link</a>
```

Once in a menu that is working is:

```
<a href="admin.php?page=layouts/admin-layout.php" class="wp-first-item current" aria-current="page">Acesso Rapido</a>
```